# Multiplication rule problem

Tags: combinatorics

In a boutique, they offer six different shirts. Moreover you are
allowed to get a discount on a pair of shoes for any shirt you buy. If you choose to buy a shirt it will cost \$$1$, while the shoes and the shirt together will cost you \$$2$. If you have \$$12$ in total, how many different combinations of shoes and shirts can you buy.

Comment: Why is this a multiplication rule problem?  What constitutes a combination?  You can buy $0$ to $6$ pairs and buy enough shirts to spend the rest of the money.  Is that $7$ combinations?

Comment: I feel like it should be noted that the problem never states that you must spend all your money. This means that there are more combinations then @jvdhooft  suggested.

Comment: I should have made it more clear. Lets say you have shirts {a,b,c,d,e,f} .You can buy {a} with shoes and that is a possible combination that costs $2. I'm trying to find all the possible combinations without going over the 12 mark.

Comment: how much do she shoes cost each? are they distinguishable from one another?? (shoes by themselves)

Comment: @SakethMalyala they are distinguishable from each other, but they must come with a shirt. Each shirt has a pair of shoes that have to go with it. You can get the shirt by itself, but not without the shoes.

Comment: can you buy two of the same shirt?

Comment: @SakethMalyala no, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be handled in a straightforward way. For every shirt/shoes combination, there are three options: buy the shirt, buy the shirt and the shoes or buy nothing. As such, the total amount of combinations equals:

$$3^6=729$$

If you must buy at least one item, there are 728 valid options.

Answer (score 1):

Break into $7$ cases:

Buy $6$ shirts and $0-6$ shoes.

Buy $5$ shirts and $0-5$ shoes.

...

Buy nothing at all.

Case $0$: $1$ way to buy nothing.

Case $1$: Choose $1$ shirt from $6$, then choose whether to buy the corresponding shoes. $\displaystyle \binom{6}{1}(2)$.

---

Notice, I could buy $0$ shoes or $1$ shoes so what I did was $\displaystyle \binom{1}{0}+\binom{1}{1}=2^1$.

In general, $\displaystyle \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n}=2^n$, and that is pivotal to solving this problem quickly.

---

Case 2: Choose 2 shirts from $6$, then choose $0$ $1$ or $2$ shoes from the shirts, $\displaystyle \binom{6}{2}(2^2)$.

Following similar logic for the rest of the cases gives us a total probability of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^6 \binom{6}{k}2^k=\boxed{729}$ combinations.

---

---

If you don't consider nothing an option, then $\boxed{728}$ options.

The beauty of this is that there is literally no way to go over the price limit.